# Stuck on text calculator

Tags: python-3.x

When I run this code it outputs"enter the first number." and allows for input, then repeats. I have no idea what the problem is. I've also heard on here that it would be easier to use eval. I haven't looked into it yet, but I plan to.
P.S.: As I'm sure you can see, there is extraneous code I put in to try to figure out what was going on.

```
condition0=False
condition1=0
x=1

while 1==1:

while condition0==True:
    restart=input("to restart calculations enter \'true\'")

    if restart != "true":
        numone=answer
        condition1=1
    else:
        condition1=0

while condition1==0:
    numone=input("Enter the first number: ")
try:
    numone=int(numone)
    condition1=1
except ValueError:
    print("you must enter an integer!")
    condition1=0

condition2=0
while condition2==0:
    operator = input("Enter the operator(+,-,*,/):")
if operator=="+"|operator=="-"|operator=="*"|operator=="/":
    condition2=1
else:
    print("you must enter an operator!")
    condition2=0

condition3=0
while condition3==0:
    numtwo=input("Enter another number: ")
try:
    numtwo=int(numtwo)
    condition3=1
except ValueError:
    print('you must enter an integer!')
    condition3=0

if operator== '+':
    answer=int(numone)+int(numtwo)
    print(answer)
    print("test")

elif operator == "-":
    answer=int(numone)-int(numtwo)
    print(answer)

elif operator == "*":
    answer=int(numone)*int(numtwo)
    print(answer)

elif operator == "/":
    answer=int(numone)/int(numtwo)
    print(answer)

else:
    print("something went wrong")

print(x + "time(s) through the while loop")
condition0=True
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the actual indentation of your code? If so, the try and except blocks need to be indented under the while loop above it so the `condition1` value changes. Otherwise it's just going through the while loop over and over again. This applies to a couple of your loops.

```
while condition1==0:
    numone=input("Enter the first number: ")
    try:
        numone=int(numone)
        condition1=1
    except ValueError:
        print("you must enter an integer!")
        condition1=0

condition2=0
while condition2==0:
    operator = input("Enter the operator(+,-,*,/):")
    if operator=="+"|operator=="-"|operator=="*"|operator=="/":
        condition2=1
    else:
        print("you must enter an operator!")
        condition2=0

condition3=0
while condition3==0:
    numtwo=input("Enter another number: ")
    try:
        numtwo=int(numtwo)
        condition3=1
    except ValueError:
        print('you must enter an integer!')
        condition3=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while condition1==0:
    numone=input("Enter the first number: ")
try:
    numone=int(numone)
    condition1=1
except ValueError:
    print("you must enter an integer!")
    condition1=0
...(the rest of the code)
```

Now `try` and the rest of the code is not inside the `while` scope. So the program is going to ask for numone until while `condition1` is equal to zero. And it is always going to be equal to zero, because `condition1` is never changed inside the loop.
I guess, it should be like this:

```
while condition1==0:
    numone=input("Enter the first number: ")
    try:
        numone=int(numone)
        condition1=1
    except ValueError:
        print("you must enter an integer!")
        condition1=0
```

Comment: @user2465510, it's easy to miss somethig obvious sometimes. All you need is someone else's sight :)